# Seed mongodb not working (docker-compose)

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I tried the init.js solution that contains the script to insert data into the collection that I saw in other questions here,
but it just didn't work, I can see that the .js file
is inside the container in folder "/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d". but for some reason it doesn't
populate the collection.

This is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
      - rabbitmq
      - nginx

  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro

  mongodb:
    image: mongo:latest
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    environment:
      # - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=test
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=admin
      - MONGO_URI="mongodb://admin:admin@mongodb:27017/"
    volumes:
      - ./mongo-init/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/:ro 
      - mongodb_data:/data/db

  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express:latest
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=admin
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=admin
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=mongodb
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_PORT=27017
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ENABLE_ADMIN=true
      - ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_USERNAME=admin
      - ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_PASSWORD=admin
    depends_on:
      - mongodb

  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3-management
    container_name: rabbitmq
    restart: always
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=admin
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=admin
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_VHOST=/
    ports:
      - 15672:15672
    volumes:
      - rabbitmq_data:/var/lib/rabbitmq

volumes:
  mongodb_data: 
  rabbitmq_data:
```

/mongo-init/init.js

```
db = db.getSiblingDB('test');
db.createUser({
  user: 'test',
  pwd: 'test',
  roles: [
    {
      role: 'readWrite',
      db: 'test',
    },
  ],
});

db.createCollection('haha');

db.haha.insertOne({ name: 'haha' });
```

my root folder structure is:

```
 .
    ├── app 
        └──app.py 
    ├── mongo-init
        └── mongo-init.js 
    └── Dockerfile 
    └── docker-compose.yml 
    └── nginx.conf 
    └── pyproject.toml 
    └── poetry.lock
```

I tried this option from the mongo-init.js file
file that I saw in another question here on stackoverflow, but even replicating exactly what was said in the answers to that other question, I didn't succeed.

i access localhost 8081 using mongo-express to check the collections and see if the data has been created and i never see either the collection or the data. i.e. init.js is not running.

And even via a route in the api it doesn't return anything either, just an empty array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the docs](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo), scripts in `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/` scripts are only executed *when a container is started for the first time*.

Since you have created the container before, the data dir exists and has data in it, including the already created DBs and collections. So it's not considered a *"first time" start* and the initdb.d scripts won't be executed.

Stop the container, delete that dir - `mongodb_data` in your case - and then start the container. Without a datadir, it's considered new/first time and will execute the scripts.

Look out for the logs and messages when you do `docker compose up`.

Comment: Thank you so much @aneroid! Why this happen?

Comment: @Louis It happens because if the data dir exists, it's not considered a _"first time" start_ and the initdb.d scripts won't be executed.