# Mongodb in docker doesn't run init scripts

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

So, I'm trying to run basic init script for mongodb in docker.
Here's the script:

```
db = db.getSiblingDB('admin');
db.createUser({
  user: "name",
  pwd: "password",
  roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" }, "readWriteAnyDatabase" ]
});
```

Here's my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - mongo
  mongo:
    image: mongo:latest
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - mongodbdata:/data/db
      - ./docker/init-mongo.js:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init-mongo.js:ro
      - ./docker/mongodb.conf:/etc/mongodb.conf
    command: ["--auth"]
volumes:
  mongodbdata:
    external: true
```

There's no error in logs, completely nothing. File is in docker with correct content. But script is like just ignored.
I looked for any reason for not running this script, but internet seem like doesn't have anything for this case. Also i tried to change script, read official documentations, ask chatgpt.. Absolutely nothing helps

Comment: TL;DR: delete everything inside your `mongodbdata` and then start the service. If that dir is not empty, then it won't re-execute init scripts. [Details here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77675681/1431750).